# get_post_meta not extracting title,permalink and posttype

Tags: post-meta

i need to extract the `post_type`, `title` of the post and the `permalink` using get_post_meta i am trying following code for the same

```
$title=get_post_meta($post_id,'title',true);
$permalink=get_post_meta($post_id,'the_permalink',true);
$posttype=get_post_meta($post_id,'post_type',true);
```

its doesn't return anything. variables are always empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post metas are used for storing custom data that you want to store and retrieve yourself. The default post data `post type`, `title`, `permalink` are not saved in post meta. You can retrieve `post_type` and `title` using [get_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function which returns a [WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object. For permalink you need to use [get_permalink()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function like this.

```
$post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $post->post_title;
$posttype = $post->post_type;
$permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
```

Comment: any other way for permalink as my code get_permalink is not working . trying to get it to work with a plugin.

Comment: @user3449454 why won't it work, are you giving invalid post_id?

Comment: yep i m ...i i m trying to exctract the permalink of post created by wpallimport plugin for some reason it extracts the title and posttype correctly using the code u gave but the permalink it doessn't

Comment: Even if the plugin create some custom post type, `get_permalink()` function should work. Maybe there is some problem on their part. You need to contact them to resolve this issue. I don't know how wpallimport works and can't give any suggestion on this. Also note that third party plugin related questions are off-topic here.

Comment: will something like $post->the_permalink; be valid?

Comment: if you look at the `WP_POST` object, there is no value like `the_permalink`. So, it won't work. You can try using `get_post_permalink()` instead of `get_peramlink()`.